# How do I get the project basepath in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have created a folder as user in the root directory.

My project base path is:

```
/var/www/myproject/
```

When I want to access the base path as BASEPATH from a controller it's showing:

```
/var/www/myproject/system/
```

But I want the path to be:

```
/var/www/myproject/
```

I am new to CodeIgniter. How do I set this path?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792268/how-to-set-proper-codeigniter-base-url

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Use FCPATH instead of BASEPATH for more check this link.

[Codeigniter - dynamically getting relative/absolute path outside of application folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242972/codeigniter-how-to-get-realitive-absolute-path-dynamically-just-outside-of-appli)

Answer (score 25):

use `base_url()`

```
echo $baseurl=base_url();
```

if you need to pass url to a function then use `site_url()`

```
 echo site_url('controller/function');
```

if you need the root path then  `FCPATH`..

```
echo FCPATH;
```

Comment: I am using **base_url()** to get path, but instead of localhost it's giving me server path. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 16):

Following are the build-in **constants** you can use as per your requirements for getting the paths in *Codeigniter*:

```
EXT: The PHP file extension

FCPATH: Path to the front controller (this file) (root of CI)

SELF: The name of THIS file (index.php)

BASEPATH: Path to the system folder

APPPATH: The path to the “application” folder
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Codeigniter has a function that retrieves your base path which is:

```
FCPATH and BASEPATH i recommand use FCPATH.
```

for your base url use:

```
<?=base_url()?>
```

if your php short tag is off

```
<?php echo base_url(); ?>
```

for example: if you want to link you css files which is in your base path

```
<script src='<?=base_url()?>js/jquery.js' type='text/javascript' />
```

Comment: That's not the base path, but the base url

Comment: He didnt ask for base url

Comment: but... what if he is in the deep of url? the base_url wouldn't just be the root but in C.I v3 it will include right until last /controller/

Answer (score 2):

Obviously you mean the baseurl. If so:

> base url: URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your
>   base URL, | WITH a trailing slash.

Root in codeigniter specifically means that the position where you can append your controller to your url.

For example, if the root is  `localhost/ci_installation/index.php/`, then to access the `mycont` controller you should go to `localhost/ci_installation/index.php/mycont`.

So, instead of writing such a long link you can (*after loading "url" helper*) , replace the term `localhost/ci_installation/index.php/` by `base_url()` and this function will return the same string url.

*NOTE: if you hadn't appended `index.php/` to your `base_url` in your `config.php`, then if you use `base_url()`, it will return something like that `localhost/ci_installation/mycont`. And that will not work, because you have to access your controllers from `index.php`, instead of that you can place a `.htaccess` file to your codeigniter installation position. Cope that the below code to it:*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /imguplod/index.php/$1 [L]
```

And it should work :)

Comment: and basepath reffering to the system directory link within your codeigniter , it is another subject

Comment: @petreh , im badly sorry for the bad language age and thank you for the modification i just hoped to help ,thanks

Comment: but 'inchaa'allah' it is an islamic arabic expression means that we hope god to accept some request or make something real

Answer (score -1):

Change your default controller which is in config file.

i.e : config/routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "Your controller name";
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: This does not help. The question asked how to get the root path... The default/front controller path is the `FCPATH`, changing the default controller name in _routes.php_ will not change this path...