# Codeigniter home page working fine but showing 404 for other pages

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have uploaded working codeignter application on public ip for testing. 
Home page is working fine but other pages are not working.

but i can access inner files as below:
http://ip-address/index.php/about-us/who-we-are

My files are as below:

```
**config.php**

$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';


**routes.php**

$route['about-us/(:any)'] = "page/aboutUs/$1";
$route['contact-us/(:any)'] = "page/contactus/$1";
$route['plan-articles'] = "page/planArticles";

$route['(:any)'] = "page/$1";

$route['default_controller'] = "page";
$route['404_override'] = '';


**.htacess**

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|fav\.ico|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: are you on the root folder or subfolder?

Comment: on root folder but i can access inner files as `http://ip-address/index.php/about-us/who-we-are`

Comment: is that a right link? try to put the whole domain into you base_url

Comment: if you upload from the windows problem may in lower and upper cases of filenames,
Do you receive 404 error?

Comment: Change this `$route['about-us/(:any)'] = "page/aboutUs/$1";` to this `$route['about-us/(:any)'] = "page/index.php/aboutUs/$1";`

Answer (score 1):

Issue is there as your project specific .htaccess file is not being called from Apache server.

You have to check in apache httpd.conf whether `"AllowOverride All"` is active or not.

Answer (score 1):

I did several projects with CI. Never got a error like that.

use this .htacess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

For Extra Knowledge :

if you bother about your URL and how it looks like, you can use different controllers to each page.

if product page use product controller, if About Us page
u can use aboutUs. then your URL look like `www.example.com/product/` or `www.example.com/aboutUs/`.

So each and every controller you can use functions and can do much much. `$route` is also best method. But this is the most easiest method.

Answer (score 0):

Create each page as a controller/view
Then you can redirect to the controller, which loads the view.

layout example:

```
application/controllers/main.php
application/controllers/page1.php
application/views/main.php
application/views/page1.php
```

This might help: [How do I get the project basepath in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188594/how-do-i-get-the-project-basepath-in-codeigniter)