# Codeigniter. Web app works fine in local but in live server it only load the home page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I currently working in a web app using `Codeigniter` framework. It works well locally with `Wampserver32` but when passing it to a live `apache` server it only loads the home page and when I try to route to another page it goes: Error - 404

I've already tried changing:

1- `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` to`$config['index_page'] = 'index.php'?;`

2- `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';` to `$config['uri_protocol']   = 'PATH_INFO';`

I've actually blocked for 1 day.

---

**confing.php file**

```
...
$config['base_url'] = 'http://s661658794.onlinehome.fr/admin';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
...
```

---

**routes.php file**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['Admin'] = 'admin/Login';
$route['Login'] = 'admin/Login/dashboard';
$route['Home'] = 'admin/Home';
$route['Userinfo'] = 'admin/Usercontroller';
$route['History'] = 'admin/Historycontroller';
$route['Changepassword'] = 'admin/Changepassword';
$route['Notification'] = 'admin/Notification';
$route['Logout'] = 'admin/Login/logout';
$route['Forgotpassword'] = 'admin/Login/Forgotpassword';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

---

**.htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 year"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##


<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

---

**folders**

```
-/
---admin
------application
------assets
------system
------user_guide
```

Comment: any live links there for us ??

Comment: Are you sure you uploaded .htaccess? Have you checked all of your file/folder permissions and ownership?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939581/codeigniter-home-page-working-fine-but-showing-404-for-other-pages?rq=1 Have you eliminated that problem?

Comment: `http://s661658794.onlinehome.fr/admin`  access ur URL and check the ERROR message first of all

Comment: Hey guys I just shut the server down so the link http://s661658794.onlinehome.fr/admin is not working for the moment. I'm going to turn it up so you can check the link

Comment: Now the server is working again. Sorry for that.

Comment: You can try just inserting a random username and password. Normally I would relink you to the same page with an connection error message.

Answer (score 0):

If your index.php file located inside of admin in public_html folder
then you need to replace it with following code.

Your code

Rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Might be work for you

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ admin/index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hey Ankit! Thanks for the answer. However I do not see the different between what you advice my to change and what I have now

Comment: Oh.. Sorry for that  answer is updated. let me know.. if its working or now i can help you over chat

Comment: I'm knew in stackoverflow. Could you add me to the chat please?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to adjust your application/config/database.php to match your apache servers database settings.

Comment: Hey wclark. I already adjusted the database.php file. But it still not working. Do you know if there is a way I could ckeck if my app connects correctly to the database?

Comment: You could do a lookup in your database to confirm it is working. Usually this is done by the password hash lookup when a user submits your login form.

Comment: Do I have to check the password hash in the data base? Sorry, I do not understand.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26222549/php-mysql-check-if-username-and-password-are-in-the-database