# Codeigniter. the app works fine in local but in live server it only load the home page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I currently working in a web app using Codeigniter framework. It works well locally with Wampserver32 but when passing it to a live apache server it only loads the home page and when I try to route to another page it goes: Error - 404

I've already tried changing:

1- `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` to `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php'?;`

2- `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';` to `$config['uri_protocol']   = 'PATH_INFO';`

I've actually blocked for 1 day.

---

**confing.php file**

```
...
$config['base_url'] = 'http://s661658794.onlinehome.fr/admin';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
...
```

---

**routes.php file**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['Admin'] = 'admin/Login';
$route['Login'] = 'admin/Login/dashboard';
$route['Home'] = 'admin/Home';
$route['Userinfo'] = 'admin/Usercontroller';
$route['History'] = 'admin/Historycontroller';
$route['Changepassword'] = 'admin/Changepassword';
$route['Notification'] = 'admin/Notification';
$route['Logout'] = 'admin/Login/logout';
$route['Forgotpassword'] = 'admin/Login/Forgotpassword';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

---

***.htaccess file***

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 year"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##


<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: try this `$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";`

Comment: also make sure your case sensitiveness for the files and url structure.

Comment: can't see this `RewriteBase /` in your **.htaccess** file.

Comment: $config['index_page']= ''  it should be rather empty

Comment: check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28709185/codeigniter-404-page-not-found-on-live-server) for more, if any of the solution from this link works for you.

Comment: Hi guys! Thanks for helps!

Comment: What I should I put in `RewriteBase /`  ?

Comment: I've already tried `$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";` but it does not work

Comment: RewriteBase / is not needed when you have the correct base_url set. Is mod_rewrite enabled on this server?

Comment: it seems rewrite_mode is not enabled on your server try phpInfo() and check its enabled or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter. Web app works fine in local but in live server it only load the home page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41288910/codeigniter-web-app-works-fine-in-local-but-in-live-server-it-only-load-the-hom)

Comment: check your version of php in apache server