# Codeigniter - switch root folder

Tags: php, codeigniter

As I know, the root folder for a codeigniter app is set in "ci.php" with the `$application_folder`variable.

Is it possible to change this variable dynamically ?

For example at at some point, in some controller,  I want to switch the root dir from "main_root" folder to "another_root" folder ?

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how I get project basepath in codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188594/how-i-get-project-basepath-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application folder is set in the index.php, for example:

```
$application_folder = '../application';
```

That is the best place to change it dynamically.

Comment: sir how to print `application folder path` or `root path`