# How to get project folder base path using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Am working at codeigniter project. I want base url for the project folder inside controller class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the project basepath in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188594/how-do-i-get-the-project-basepath-in-codeigniter)

Comment: You have `FCPATH` for the front controller whicj is the same dir of `index.php` and `APPPATH` for the apllication dir and `VIEWPATH` for the views dir and `BASEPATH` for the system dir.

Answer (score 0):

You can use base url like this way:

```
<?=base_url()?> or <?php base_url()?>
```

for example: if you want to link you js files which is in your base path

```
<script src='<?=base_url()?>js/jquery.js' type='text/javascript' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add base url from any where its global variable

```
base_url();
```

if still don't get base url then have to edit config/autoload.php as

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```